# What does "induce a topology" mean in this specific problem?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

A metric $d'$ is called equivalent to a metric $d$ if there are constants $c_0, c_1 > 0 $ sucht that

$$
c_0 d(x,y) \leq d'(x,y) \leq c_1 d(x,y)
$$
for all $x,y \in X$. Show that equivalent metrics induce the same topology on $X$

So I understand that if I have to equivalent metrics I shall show that the induce the same topology. But what does it mean for a metric to induce a topology in this problem?

Comment: Do you know what a topology is? Every metrics lets you define a topology on the set.

Answer (score 1):

Given a metric $d$ on a set $X$, the topology on $X$ induced by $d$ is the topology generated by open balls defined using $d$.  That is, a subset $U\subseteq X$ is open in this topology iff for each $x\in U$ there exists $r>0$ such that $\{y\in X:d(x,y)<r\}\subseteq U$.

Answer (score 0):

In a metric space $X$ with a metric $d$, open balls of the form

$$B_\epsilon(y) = \{x \in X : d(x,y) < \epsilon\}$$

are defined to be open sets. The induced topology is the collection of all sets generated by these open balls through unions, complements, and finite intersections.

Comment: And the balls are a basis for the topology?

Comment: @Olba12 Yes. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Open_and_closed_sets.2C_topology_and_convergence) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The topology induced by the metric is the topology with the set of balls (with respect to the metric) as a basis.

When you see an action verb in mathematics it must have some translation to an existential statement or definition because nothing "happens" in ZF or ZFC.